# Understanding how values are populated in a table for a Knapsack approach

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am referring to the following [documentation](http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/education/5MC10/Solutions/knapsack.pdf) for the dynamic programming approach and referring to the page 12 for the formula and page 13 example , screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Since in the above table, everything is zero until `V[1,5]`, I decided to calculate its value which is 10 by substituting the values in the formula mentioned in the Page 12. My calculations are as follows :

```
V[1,5] = max ( V[0,10] , v1 + V[0,5] )

       =  max ( V[0,10] , 0 + V[0,10-0])

       =  max ( 0 , 0 ) 

       =   0
```

I am wondering, how are they getting value `10` as shown in the table. Please explain if I am following any wrong approach in calculating the values.